# Export Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, export

I am trying to export an array that has multiple pdf path and pdf name.

The code looks like this:

```
// select the resource from dom

var PDF = document.querySelectorAll('a[target="_blank"]');

// create array to loop each pathname and pdf name
Array.from(PDF).forEach(function(textContent, i) {
    textContent.value = PDF[i].pathname.substring(24) + ' ' + PDF[i].textContent;
    console.log(textContent.value);

    // download
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(textContent.value);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'myFile.txt';
    hiddenElement.click();
  }

);
```

Of course this is looping and creating a text file for each pdf resource.

Do you have any input that could point me into having 1 txt file with all pdf names+location?

This is going to be only for my personal use as i need it to gather all the pdf names+location for approx. 300 html pages.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
var PDF = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[target="_blank"]'), function(el) {
  PDFString = el.pathname.substring(24) +' ' + el.innerHTML;
  return PDFString;
}).join();

var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(PDF);
hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
hiddenElement.download = 'PDFName.txt';
hiddenElement.click();
```

This will download me the location plus the name of the pdf.